# Resque gem get current worker id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using resque gem, is there any ways to get current worker id as I enabled worker in que.

`id = Resque.enqueue(MyWorker, myparams)`

I want resque to store current worker id in to id variable

Comment: what do you  mean with **que**?

Comment: Resque won't know any "worker id" at that point, since you just put the job in queue, it hasn't been picked up by a worker yet.